# NSURLSession background configuration benefits on macOS

Tags: macos, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

On iOS it’s critical to init a NSURLSession with a background configuration to get the benefit of uploading and downloading while the app is background:

Example in Swift 2:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("SomeSessionName");
NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil);
```

On OSX 10.10+, is there any benefit to using a background session configuration with the intention to continually upload or download even when the app is not currently in focus? In my experience, a default session configuration is far less vulnerable to bugs:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil);
```

Answer (score 4):

On OS X, background download tasks continue to run even after the user quits the app (as long as the user doesn't force-quit the app, IIRC).  Unlike iOS, it doesn't relaunch your app in the background when the download finishes; your app will instead find out that the download finished after the user manually relaunches the app and your app reassociates itself with the existing named background sessions.

So the most common reason for using them on OS X would be for things like games that download large data sets.  You could kick off the download in the background and let the user continue playing the game (without the expanded levels or whatever), and the download would continue even if the user quits the game, but the next time the user runs the game, the download would be available for installation.

That said, it is significantly less critical on OS X, because you have the option of forking a child process that keeps running and downloading.